# Can't add record to join table with composite unique index in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

IMPORTANT - READ EDIT BELOW FOR UPDATE ON THE ISSUE

I'm getting what I think is a bogus error when I try to add a new record to a join table with a unique composite key index on SQLite3. Note that for all (manual) tests I've done, the database has been completely rebuilt through db:drop followed by db:migrate.

**The error:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  SQLite3::ConstraintException: columns adventurer_id, item_id are not unique: 
  INSERT INTO "adventurers_items" ("adventurer_id", "item_id") VALUES (1, 68)
```

**The code that generates the error:**

```
class Adventurer < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :set_starting_skills
  after_create :set_starting_items

  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

  # automatically add starting skills on creation
  def set_starting_skills
    self.skills = self.profession.starting_skills
  end

  # automatically add starting items on creation
  def set_starting_items
    self.items = self.profession.items
  end
```

**The migration creating the join table adventurers_skills:**

```
class AdventurersItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :adventurers_items do |t|
      t.integer :item_id, :null => false
      t.integer :adventurer_id, :null => false
   end

add_index :adventurers_items, :item_id
add_index :adventurers_items, :adventurer_id
add_index :adventurers_items, [:adventurer_id, :item_id], :unique => true
```

The table exists and is completely empty. Why is my application failing to insert this record due to the uniqueness constraint? I also have the same error with an equivalent table "adventurers_skills" -- am I doing something wrong architecturally?

**EDIT**

The system is trying to add the same item/skill twice. When I change the private method to this:

```
def set_starting_skills
  skills = profession.starting_skills
end
```

It doesn't attempt to create anything in the join table. But reverting the first line to self.skills as below attempts to create the same skill TWICE

```
def set_starting_skills
  self.skills = profession.starting_skills
end
```

returns

```
(0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "adventurers_skills" ("adventurer_id", "skill_id") VALUES (4, 54)
(4.9ms)  INSERT INTO "adventurers_skills" ("adventurer_id", "skill_id") VALUES (4, 54)
SQLite3::ConstraintException: columns adventurer_id, skill_id are not unique: 
INSERT INTO "adventurers_skills" ("adventurer_id", "skill_id") VALUES (4, 54)
(3.2ms)  rollback transaction
```

There is only one skill returned for `profession.starting_skills`:

```
1.9.3-p194 :022 > Profession.find(7).starting_skills.each {|x| puts x.id}
54
```

So the real question has become: why is Rails trying to add this HABTM record twice?

Comment: Please show us the code that gives you that error. The model and the migration aren't actually inserting data. Something else is, though. So please show us that "something else"

Comment: Hmmm there was a bug calling the callback method twice somewhere and thus it tried to insert an item twice.

Comment: So, did you resolve this issue? Because I'm getting exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the callback declaration (`after_create :set_starting_skills`) **after** the relation declaration (`has_and_belongs_to_many :skills`).

i.e. The ordering of the lines in the model is significant else you get this bug.

This is madness, and there is [a GitHub issue for it](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3639).